# Concatenate a string if it is not blank

Tags: ruby

Is it possible in one line to print `error_details` only if it is not blank or `nil`?

```
log_err("#{error_code} - #{error_details}")
```

I guess I could set `error_details = ''` at the top. I am wondering if I can avoid that line of code.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of possible way:

```
error_code = 'xxx'
error_details = ''

[error_code, error_details].join(['', nil].include?(error_details) ? '' : ' - ')
# or
[error_code, error_details].compact.reject(&:empty?).join(' - ')

#=> "xxx"
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (and possibly fastest) code might look like this:

```
"#{error_code}#{' - ' unless error_details.to_s.empty?}#{error_details}"
```

Testing:

```
error_code = 'test'
error_details = nil
#=> "test"

error_code = 'test'
error_details = ''
#=> "test"

error_code = 'test'
error_details = 'details'
#=> "test - details"
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is that if you're using Rails, you can do `unless error_details.blank?`, which would do a `nil?` check and a `empty?` check, eliminating the need to turn nil into a blank string (saves you a string allocation in memory).

Comment: @Nate, Yes, you're absolutely right! I've used `to_s.empty?` because question has only tag **ruby**  without **ruby-on-rails**, but your comment adds useful info for **Rails** developers who will read this answer. Thank you!

Comment: totally agree! Yeah, sometimes I like to sprinkle in a little Rails stuff (with a Rails Only disclaimer), since Rails people search Ruby tags too. But your answer is perfect for the exact reason you said, and doesn’t make pointless arrays to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunalely [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) does not discard `nil`s, hence one needs to cleanup empties themselves:

```
log_err [error_code, error_details].
  map(&:to_s).reject(&:empty?).join(' — ')
```

But probably this would suffice:

```
log_err(
  "#{error_code} - #{error_details}".gsub(/\s*-\s*\z/, '')
)
```

Comment: `select {|o| o && o.size > 0}`?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need special consideration because an empty string and `nil` both become an empty string in string interpolation.

Thus, when `error_code` is `"foo"`, and `error_details` is `""` or `nil`, then:

```
"#{error_code} - #{error_details}"
# => "foo - "
```

Here, no content of `error_details` is included, just as you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

```
"#{error_code} - #{error_details}".partition(/ - $/).first
'foo - bar' => 'foo - bar'
'foo - '    => 'foo'
'foo -    ' => 'foo -    '
```

`/ - $/`

All we are doing is finding the `-` pattern and ensuring it is at the end of the string.  That will remove a `nil` or `empty?` `error_details` along with the separator. Any `error_details` (even `'    '`) will not be removed. I left strings of whitespace in because it is an interesting message that should be investigated not automatically discarded.

[String#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-partition) is interesting and powerful in how it ensures that the string is split into 3 pieces.